# How to use Custom Routes with Auto Query

Tags: servicestack

Using the first example in the ServiceStack [Auto Query documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) in a project structured similar to the [EmailContacts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/EmailContacts) sample project (i.e. separate projects for the ServiceModel and ServiceInterface), how would one register the custom route "/movies" defined by the Route attribute?

```
[Route("/movies")]
public class FindMovies : QueryBase<Movie>
{
    public string[] Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

Normally, custom routes such as these can be register by passing the ServiceInterface assembly when instantiating `AppHostBase`:

```
public AppHost() : base("Email Contact Services", typeof(ContactsServices).Assembly) {}
```

However, the `FindMovies` request DTO does not have an associated service and therefore won't be included. No routes are registered.

If I pass `typeof(FindMovies).Assembly` instead of or in addition to `typeof(ContactsServices).Assembly`, then the pre-defined route will be registered (i.e. shows up in the metadata, postman, etc.) but the custom route is still not registered (i.e. does not show up in the metadata, postman, etc.).

What is the best way to register the custom route using attributes when there is no service and the ServiceModel and ServiceInterface are in separate projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These issues should be resolved in v4.0.24+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

There's a new `AutoQueryFeature.LoadFromAssemblies` property to specify an additional list of assemblies to scan for `IQuery` Request DTO's. This automatically looks in the assemblies where your other Request DTO's are defined so in most cases nothing needs to be done as it will automatically be able to find your query services.

The routes for Query DTO's should now appear on the metadata pages as well as Swagger and Postman metadata API's.

Comment: Thanks, the custom routes are showing up after applying the update. FYI, TypesMetadata and TypesCSharp are now showing up under Operations on the metadata page, which weren't there before. Is this intentional? I would prefer to only see items under Operations that are useful for consumers of my API.

Comment: @timb that relates to something else I'm currently working on, it will be moved under **Plugin Links** by the next release.